# Axios was able to read the data from the api but it doesn't render react native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

1. Hi guys, I'm consuming data from pokemon's API, if I give a
   console.log inside the first request in useEffect it shows the data,
   but if I try to render my component in the flatlist no information
   is displayed.

Application component is rendering card component via simple list

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';
// import { SearchInput } from './src/components/Search/index';
import { Card } from './src/components/Card/index';
// import {api} from './src/services/api';  

export function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data.results)
        console.log(response.data.results)
      })
  }, [])
 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Pokédex</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        Search for Pokémon by name or using 
        the National Pokémon number.
      </Text>
      {/* <SearchInput /> */}

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
            >
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput 
                            placeholder="What Pokémon are you looking for?" 
                            placeholderTextColor="#c4c4c4" 
                            style={styles.textInput} 
                            // value={search} 
                            // onChangeText={text => setSearch(text)} 
                        />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      <FlatList 
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Card nome={item.nome} /> }
      />    
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 40,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#c4c4c4',
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 60,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    color: "#747476",
    fontSize: 16,
    },
});
```

The card component takes the component props and displays it in the app component

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

export function Card(props){

    const bgImg = '../../assets/#001.png';

  return (
        <View>
            <ImageBackground source={require(bgImg)} style={styles.bgImg}>
                <View style={styles.cardComponent}>
                    <Text style={styles.idText}>#{props.id}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.nomeText}>{props.name}</Text>
                    {/* <View style={styles.power}>
                        <Text style={[styles.powerText, {backgroundColor: '#A552CC', marginRight: 10}]}>{props.grass}</Text>
                        <Text style={[styles.powerText, {backgroundColor: '#62B957'}]}>{props.poison}</Text>
                    </View> */}
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bgImg: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        width: '100%',
    },
    cardComponent: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#8BBE8A',
    },
    idText: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: "rgba(23, 23, 27, 0.6)",
    },
    nomeText: {
        fontSize: 26,
        color: "#fff",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        marginBottom: 5
    },
    power: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    powerText: {
        // flex: 1,
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderRadius: 3,
        width: 61,
        height: 25,
        padding: 3,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```

Comment: You deconstructed your item when there's no need to. Change your renderitem to {(item)} => {}

Comment: So my code would look like this? 

`<FlatList 
        data={data}
        renderItem={( item ) => <Card nome={item.nome} /> }
        
 /> `

If so, I changed it and it's still the same.

A detail that I didn't write, when I hover over data={data} it appears like this const data: any[]

Comment: I managed to solve it, the caslawter solution
 It worked, but I had to add one more detail. In the <Card /> component I was passing item.name but it was to write item.item.name